# Firebase Android: to change getter in GSON model

Tags: android, json, firebase, gson, firebase-realtime-database

I have a json:

```
   {
      "station": {
        "decription": "",
        "geo": {
          "lat": "55.8",
          "lng": "25.2"
        },
        "htlist": [
          "05:31",
          "06:16",
          "06:56",
          "07:36",
          "08:16",
          "10:16"
        ],
        "name": "Station name",
        "number": "7",
        "sid": "9998",
        "wtlist": [
          "05:31",
          "06:16",
          "06:56",
          "07:36",
          "23:16"
        ]
      }
    }
```

And Model:

```
public class Station {

    @SerializedName("decription")
    @Expose
    private String decription;
    @SerializedName("geo")
    @Expose
    private Geo geo;
    @SerializedName("htlist")
    @Expose
    private List<String> htlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("number")
    @Expose
    private String number;
    @SerializedName("sid")
    @Expose
    private String sid;
    @SerializedName("wtlist")
    @Expose
    private List<String> wtlist = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getDecription() {
        return decription;
    }

    public void setDecription(String decription) {
        this.decription = decription;
    }


    public Geo getGeo() {
        return geo;
    }

    public void setGeo(Geo geo) {
        this.geo = geo;
    }

    public List<String> getHtlist() {
        return htlist;
    }

    public void setHtlist(List<String> htlist) {
        this.htlist = htlist;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public void setNumber(String number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public String getSid() {
        return sid;
    }

    public void setSid(String sid) {
        this.sid = sid;
    }

    public List<String> getWtlist() {
        return wtlist;
    }

    public void setWtlist(List<String> wtlist) {
        this.wtlist = wtlist;
    }

}
```

What I found ?

When I have tried to change:

```
public List<String> getWtlist() {
    return wtlist;
}
```

to `getWeekendTimeList()` the GSON doesn't use this field. The size of the list is always 0.

The question:

For what reasons it happens ? Is it `GSON` or `Firebase` bug? (I don't have this problem with `GSON` before) How to change getter method to avoid breakage in the code ?

Comment: You are already using `getWeekendTimeList()` that returns `htlist` in your code. This exact code is working as expected. What should I do to replicate the problem?

Comment: @MohanadMohie it's my bad, I have edited my model. I'm using Firebase, maybe the problem is there

Comment: I can't see why Firebase would affect your Gson parser, as long as the JSON String is the same. When I tried it with the static JSON String it worked normally even after changing the method name. The best workaround I can suggest is adding another method called `getWeekendTimeList` that returns `getWtlist`.